# Connected to VPN but Chome shows usual IP

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

I use a VPN and normally at home I'm connected directly to the home network and my VPN (Newshosting) works fine (I think).

Currently I'm using a plug-in WiFi adaptor and although the VPN client says it's connected, when I use Chrome and go to WhatsMyIp, it shows it as unchanged.

I look in Chrome network settings and the VPN is the only one present in the dial-up and VPN box.

Is there something else I need to do?

Further investigation shows that www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address shows the "correct" address (i.e. via the VPN) in IPv4 format. While www.whatismyip.com shows the original IPv6 address whether I am connected to the VPN or not.

So I'm guessing I'm configured correctly for IPv4, but not for IPv6? How do I fix this?

```
=========================================================================
Interface List
 19...90 2b 34 d6 1c c7 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  
 18...00 ff 76 62 b6 8a ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9  
 17...f4 6d 04 b1 e9 37 ......ASUS 802.11n Network Adapter  
 13...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1  
 14...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8  
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1  
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter  
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
 =========================================================================  

 IPv4 Route Table  
 =========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric  
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     172.21.100.1     172.21.96.20     30  
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      172.21.96.1     172.21.96.20     30  
     81.171.85.19  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
     81.171.97.23  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
    81.171.97.193  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     172.21.100.1     172.21.96.20     30  
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      172.21.96.1     172.21.96.20     30  
      172.21.96.0    255.255.254.0         On-link      172.21.96.20    286  
     172.21.96.20  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.96.20    286  
    172.21.97.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.96.20    286  
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.18    296  
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
     192.168.0.18  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.18    296  
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.18    296  
     192.168.31.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.31.1    276  
     192.168.31.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.31.1    276  
   192.168.31.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.31.1    276  
    192.168.203.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.203.1    276  
    192.168.203.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.203.1    276  
  192.168.203.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.203.1    276  
   205.185.209.47  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.18     40  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.21.96.20    286  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.31.1    276  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.203.1    276  
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.18    296  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.21.96.20    286  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.31.1    276  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.203.1    276  
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.18    296  
 ==========================================================================  
Persistent Routes:  
  None  

IPv6 Route Table  
===========================================================================  
Active Routes:       
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway  
 17    296 ::/0                     fe80::9221:6ff:fe0b:b7c  
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link  
 17     48 2a02:c7d:e23b:ed00::/64  On-link  
 17    296 2a02:c7d:e23b:ed00:456a:634e:94ab:fe79/128  
                                    On-link  
 17    296 2a02:c7d:e23b:ed00:c5e3:e13:2238:fcc5/128  
                                    On-link  
 17     48 fde1:efe4:787d::/64      On-link  
 17    296 fde1:efe4:787d:0:456a:634e:94ab:fe79/128  
                                    On-link  
 17    296 fde1:efe4:787d:0:c5e3:e13:2238:fcc5/128  
                                    On-link  
 18    286 fe80::/64                On-link  
 13    276 fe80::/64                On-link  
 14    276 fe80::/64                On-link  
 17    296 fe80::/64                On-link  
 14    276 fe80::10e:d5c0:4c87:8df8/128  
                                    On-link  
 13    276 fe80::194b:11ff:9b08:e1c3/128  
                                    On-link  
 18    286 fe80::21ba:285a:9b9d:1200/128  
                                    On-link  
 17    296 fe80::456a:634e:94ab:fe79/128  
                                    On-link  
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 18    286 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 13    276 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 14    276 ff00::/8                 On-link  
 17    296 ff00::/8                 On-link  

 ========================================================================   
Persistent Routes:  
  None
```

Comment: Chrome itself isn’t concerned with whatever network connections you have set up. Please provide the output of `route print`.

Comment: VPNs often only deal with IPv4 traffic - you'll find most VPNs don't passthrough IPv6 traffic, with that traffic generally going through standard connection routes.

Comment: OK, but can I force Chrome to use IPv4  - I know that some sites that ONLY use IPv6 will then be unusable.